# How do I get the MD5 sum of a directory's contents as one sum on Windows?

Tags: windows, md5, md5sum, md5-file

The md5 sum program does not provide checksums for directories but the content on them. I want to get a single MD5 checksum for the entire contents of a directory **on Windows**, including files in sub-directories. That is, one combined checksum made out of all the files. Is there a way to do this on Windows? I have to check a directory of 2TB and it gives me a lot of hashes, I need just one.
Help!